# Shiny interactive document download button overwrites original R markdown

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, r-markdown

So I'm trying to write an html R markdown document with interactive shiny bits that allow the user to edit a graph and then download the results to a pdf. However, there is something catastrophically wrong with the way that I'm trying to do this because as soon as the html starts, it overwrites the original markdown file with the contents of the pdf - turning it into complete gibberish right in the editor.

I doubt that I've found a completely new way to fail at R but I haven't been able to find where anybody else has had this issue. Additionally, I've looked over the shiny reference material and I'm just going in circles at this point, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using Rstudio 1.0.44, rmarkdown 1.2 and shiny 0.14.2. A small (not)working example:

````
---
title: "Minimum Failing Example"
author: "wittyalias"
date: "December 5, 2016"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r echo = FALSE}
library(ggplot2)

today <- Sys.Date()

inputPanel(downloadButton("dnld", label = "Download pdf"))

renderPlot({
    # Example code from http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_(ggplot2)/
    p1 <<- ggplot(ChickWeight, aes(x=Time, y=weight, colour=Diet, group=Chick)) +
    geom_line() +
    ggtitle("Growth curve for individual chicks")
    p1
})

reactive({
    fname <- paste0("Chick Weight - ", today, ".pdf")

    output$dnld <- downloadHandler(filename = fname,
                    content = makethepdf(file))

    makethepdf <- function(fname) {
        pdf(fname,
            width = 14,
            height = 8.5)
        p1
        dev.off()
}
})
```
````

EDIT: To be clear: I want the user to be able to download multiple pages of graphs, some of which will have different formatting. The user won't be downloading just a pdf version of the markdown document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so there are a number of problems with my code, but using some of the suggestions in the other answers I've been able to work it out.

The primary problem with this little document is that `content` in the downloadHandler *is a function*, but in my code I set `content` equal to the *result of a function call*. It looks like when the shiny app is first run it compiles `content`, thinking that it is a function, but actually ends up calling the function. It sends `file` as an arguement, which doesn't seem to exist except as a base function. Calling `makethepdf` with just `file` throws an error when I use it in the console, but for whatever reason in this app it just goes with the call, apparently with `file = [name of the .Rmd]` (just as OganM said).

To fix, change this:

```
output$dnld <- downloadHandler(filename = fname,
                content = makethepdf(file))
```

to

```
output$dnld <- downloadHandler(filename = fname,
                content = makethepdf)
```

To be clear: this code does not overwrite the .Rmd file if `content` calls `makethepdf` with any argument other than `file`. For instance,  `content = makethepdf(fnm))` causes the download button to display an `object not found` error and `content = makethepdf(fname))` causes the download button to throw an `attempt to apply non-function` error when pressed.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because reasons I weren't able to identify makethepdf runs with the `file = [name of the file]`. Insert a `print(fname)` to see. The download handler isn't supposed to be inside an observer though. You need to have it outside on its own. I also failed to make `pdf()` `dev.off()` combination work for some reason so here's a working version below.

```
output$dnld = downloadHandler(filename =  paste0("Chick Weight - ", today, ".pdf"),
                          content = function(file){
                              ggsave(file, plot = p1, width = 14, height = 8.5)
                          })
```

Comment: Thanks very much for that suggestion, but I need to make multiple pages in the pdf, and as far as I know, ggsave won't allow me to do that. Also, I inserted `print(fname)` both outside and inside the makethepdf function, and it returns the "Chick Weight....pdf" that I would have expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use `tempfile()` and `tempdir()` to create a temporary file:

```
 output$downloadReport = downloadHandler(

    filename = function() {
      normalizePath(tempfile("report_", fileext = ".docx"), winslash = "/")
    },

    content = function(file) {

    out = rmarkdown::render("./report.Rmd", 
                            output_file = file,
                            output_dir = tempdir(),
                            output_format = "pdf_document",
                            intermediates_dir = tempdir(),
                            envir = new.env(),
                            params = list( fontSize = 10)
  )
})
```

I usually use a separate .Rmd template for my downloaded reports as the layout and text are usually similar but not identical to what works in an app.

I also find using parameters is a convenient way to pass input settings from my app to my report.  See [this RStudio post](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_parameterized_reports.html) for details

Comment: That's a good idea, I wasn't aware that could be done. I'll look into using it tomorrow, but I'm not sure that it will work. I want to include only the graph(s), not the full markdown report. Is that possible?